# App not suspending after long-running background task completes

Tags: ios, application-lifecycle, uibackgroundtask

Why doesn't my app suspend immediately after my long-running background task completes?

An app running on iOS 8 uses a long-running background task to avoid being suspended when it enters the background. *All is well*. When the task is complete, the app invokes the background task completion handler:

```
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
        backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

However, a call to `backgroundTimeRemaining` returns a 40 second time interval.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]
```

Indeed, the app doesn't suspend for at least another 20 seconds after ending the task.

- Why is this happening?
- Will the app always receive the full execution time?
- Can I hasten app suspension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging further, it's become clear that `backgroundTimeRemaining` is not updated immediately upon task completion. The app suspends shortly afterwards, likely after a run loop spin. You should not expect `backgroundTimeRemaining` to be accurate at all times.